# How can I use a Google Cloud Function to start and stop vm instances?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, google-compute-engine

I am trying to start and stop existing google cloud compute virtual machines through a cloud function.

I found this in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/start), but I am not sure how this would work as a cloud function. How would the authentication work? How can I install a Node.js library?

```
// BEFORE RUNNING:
// ---------------
// 1. If not already done, enable the Compute Engine API
//    and check the quota for your project at
//    https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/compute
// 2. This sample uses Application Default Credentials for authentication.
//    If not already done, install the gcloud CLI from
//    https://cloud.google.com/sdk and run
//    `gcloud beta auth application-default login`.
//    For more information, see
//    https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials
// 3. Install the Node.js client library by running
//    `npm install googleapis --save`

const {google} = require('googleapis');
var compute = google.compute('v1');

authorize(function(authClient) {
  var request = {
    // Project ID for this request.
    project: 'my-project',  // TODO: Update placeholder value.

    // The name of the zone for this request.
    zone: 'my-zone',  // TODO: Update placeholder value.

    // Name of the instance resource to start.
    instance: 'my-instance',  // TODO: Update placeholder value.

    auth: authClient,
  };

  compute.instances.start(request, function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return;
    }

    // TODO: Change code below to process the `response` object:
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
  });
});

function authorize(callback) {
  google.auth.getClient({
    scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform']
  }).then(client => {
    callback(client);
  }).catch(err => {
    console.error('authentication failed: ', err);
  });
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hello, what would you like to achieve? Start a GCE VM in the morning and stop it at night i.e.?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there's a new feature in GCP. **Cloud Scheduler**, that allow users to schedule starts and  stops in GCE VMs.

[Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/quickstart) is a fully managed enterprise-grade cron job scheduler.

---

To start/stop a GCE VM Cloud Scheduler uses a Cloud Function and Pub/Sub.
[image]

There's a complete documentation [guide](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/start-and-stop-compute-engine-instances-on-a-schedule) to scheduling the compute instances with Cloud Scheduler using the Cloud Functions provided (there you would find a start instance .js function  sample [1](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/blob/HEAD/functions/scheduleinstance/index.js) and a stop instance function sample [2](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/blob/HEAD/functions/scheduleinstance/index.js)).

Following the [guide](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/start-and-stop-compute-engine-instances-on-a-schedule) you would be able to use a Google Cloud Function to start and stop GCE instances.

Answer (score 0):

To install `npm` libraries for your cloud functions:

1. Include a `package.json` in the same directory as your function (eg. `index.js`)
2. And run the `gcloud functions deploy <function name>` command from within the same directory

Note that the service account running the cloud function needs to have the necessary permissions to start/stop the VMs.

Example [code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/workflows-demos/tree/3bb2cc77438cfeabfb8d244d2b3bedc767dc3e03/callback-translation) and related [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/tutorial-callbacks-firestore#deploy-first-function).